# Trying to deploy an exploded war in arquillian

Tags: java, testing, wildfly, war, jboss-arquillian

I'm currenty trying to deploy an exploded war artifact in arquillian through wildfly. I have managed to deploy a war file but I can't figure out how to do it on a exploded war file. My current target setup is:

project/target/deployments/tekir.war(directory)

project/target/deployments/tekir.war.dodeploy

And my arquillian java code is:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive deploy(){
    return ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, new File("target/Project-Web-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war"));
}
```

What I need to do is deploying the exploded war instead of this snapshot file. How can I do that?

Comment: This is currently not possible. Is there a reason it needs to be exploded?

Comment: I presume just a general faster boot up time, because you can use Mavens/Intellijs incremental compilation to maintain an up to date exploded artifact, without having to build the entire JAR again.